# How we can compare textfield values are same value in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have register screen in android jetpack compose, and I have ScreenA and ScreenB, in ScreenA I have email and in ScreenB I have again mail and confirm mail, so I want to control those three email values is same value. In ScreenA when I put any mail, in ScreenB  both mail must be same mail with ScreenA, any solution?

**ScreenA:**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenA(
    navController: NavController,
    model: MyViewModel
) {

    val email = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
  
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
        ,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        val context = LocalContext.current

  OutlinedTextField(
            value = emailState.value,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = white,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                focusedLabelColor = Grey,
                unfocusedLabelColor = Grey,
                cursorColor = custom,
                textColor = custom,

                ),
            onValueChange = { emailState.value = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Email") },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Email") },
            singleLine = true,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f)

        )
}
```

**ScreenB:**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenB(

    navController: NavController,
    model: MyViewModel

) {

    val emailState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    val confirmEmailState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }

   Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize()  ,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {


     OutlinedTextField(
            value = emailState.value,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = white,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                focusedLabelColor = Grey,
                unfocusedLabelColor = Grey,
                cursorColor = custom,
                textColor = custom,

                ),
            onValueChange = { emailState.value = it },
            label = { Text(text = "E-mail") },
          
            singleLine = true,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f)

        )

        OutlinedTextField(
            value = confirmEmailState.value,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = white,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                focusedLabelColor = Grey,
                unfocusedLabelColor = Grey,
                cursorColor = custom,
                textColor = custom,

                ),
            onValueChange = { confirmEmailState.value = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Confirm E-mail") },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Confirm E-mail") },
            singleLine = true,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f)

        )
}
```

**viewmodel:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val db: FirebaseFirestore,
    val auth: FirebaseAuth,


) : ViewModel() {

    var singIn = mutableStateOf(false)
    var isInProgress = mutableStateOf(false)
    var popNotification = mutableStateOf<Event<String>?>(null)
    var userData = mutableStateOf<User?>(null)


    init {

        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        singIn.value = currentUser != null
        currentUser?.uid?.let { uid ->
            getUserData(uid)
        }
    }

    fun onSignOut() {
        auth.signOut()
    }

    fun onSignUp(
        email: String,
        password: String


        ) {
        if (
            email.isEmpty()

        ) {
            handledException(customMessage = "Please fill in all fields")
            return
        }

        isInProgress.value = true

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    singIn.value = true

                } else {
                    handledException(customMessage = "signed failed")
                }
                isInProgress.value = false
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {

            }
    }

    fun onSignUpEmail(
      
        emailState: String,
        confirmEmailState: String,

        ) {
        if (
      
            emailState.isEmpty() or
            confirmEmailState.isEmpty()


        ) {
            handledException(customMessage = "Please fill in all fields")
            return
        }

        isInProgress.value = true

        db.collection(USERS).whereEqualTo("email", email.replace(" ", "")).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                if (documents.size() > 0) {
                    handledException(customMessage = "mail already exist")
                    isInProgress.value = false
                } else {

                    createOrUpdateProfile(
                 
                        emailState = emailState,
                        confirmEmailState = confirmEmailState,

                        )

                    isInProgress.value = false

                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { }
    }



    private fun createOrUpdateProfile(

        emailState: String? = null,
        confirmEmailState: String? = null,
      
        ) {
        val uid = auth.currentUser?.uid
        val userData = User(
        
            emailState = emailState ?: userData.value?.emailState,
            confirmEmailState = confirmEmailState ?: userData.value?.confirmEmailState,
  
        )
        uid?.let {
            isInProgress.value = true
            db.collection(USERS).document(uid).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    if (it.exists()) {
                        it.reference.update(userData.toMap())
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                this.userData.value = userData
                                isInProgress.value = false
                            }
                            .addOnFailureListener {
                                handledException(customMessage = "Cannot Update user")
                                isInProgress.value = false

                            }
                    } else {
                        db.collection(USERS).document(uid).set(userData)
                        getUserData(uid)
                        isInProgress.value = false
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    handledException(exception, "Cannot create user")
                    isInProgress.value = false
                }
        }
    }

    private fun getUserData(uid: String) {
        isInProgress.value = true
        db.collection(USERS).document(uid).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                val user = it.toObject<User>()
                userData.value = user
                isInProgress.value = false

            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                handledException(exception, "Cannot retrieve user data")
                isInProgress.value = false
            }
    }

    fun onLogin(email: String, pass: String) {
        if (email.isEmpty() or pass.isEmpty()) {
            handledException(customMessage = "Please fill in all fields")
            return
        }
        isInProgress.value = true
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    singIn.value = true
                    isInProgress.value = false
                    auth.currentUser?.uid?.let { uid ->
//                        handledException(customMessage = "Login success")
                        getUserData(uid)
                    }
                } else {
                    handledException(task.exception, "Login failed")
                    isInProgress.value = false
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exc ->
                handledException(exc, "Login failed")
                isInProgress.value = false
            }
    }

    private fun handledException(exception: Exception? = null, customMessage: String = "") {
        exception?.printStackTrace()
        val errorMsg = exception?.message ?: ""
        val message = if (customMessage.isEmpty()) {
            errorMsg
        } else {
            "$customMessage: $errorMsg"
        }
        popNotification.value = Event(message)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Move emailState to your viewModel. You can also convert it to Flow, but it is not obligatory.

It looks like that in your viewmodel:

```
val emailStateA = MutableStateFlow(TextFieldValue())
val emailStateB = MutableStateFlow(TextFieldValue()) 
val areEmailsEqual = MutableStateFlow(true) 
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
       combine(emailStateA, emailStateB) { a, b -> 
           areEmailsEqual.emit(a == b) }.collect() 
    }       
}
```

Comment: tnx so much for ur answer, is it possible to give clear answer

Comment: @SpaceDevs sure, if you are using the save viewModel for both of your fragments, then you can store email state inside the viewModel, so all OutlinedTextField use the state directly from viewModel.

Comment: how u will controll 3 mail same

Comment: @SpaceDevs Could you share a full code with viewModel implementation?

Comment: I update question

Comment: Add in ViewModel this: val emailState = mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())

Then use  "viewModel.emailState.value" instead of "emailState.value" in your fragment.
If your viewmodel is shared between ScreenA and ScreenB, thats all. If not, you can share the viewModel between them using Hilt

Comment: I want to give notification if in screenB mail not same with screenA and make button inactive in screenB

Comment: ahh, got it now, do it like that in your viewmodel: 
    val emailStateA = MutableStateFlow(TextFieldValue())
    val emailStateB = MutableStateFlow(TextFieldValue())
    val areEmailsEqual = MutableStateFlow(true)

    init {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            combine(emailStateA, emailStateB) { a, b ->
                areEmailsEqual.emit(a == b)
            }.collect()
        }
    }

Comment: is it possible update your answer :)

Comment: it is not work, I want to use mail the same, check them it is same, if mail not same, button will not be active